# Django wait to finish Selenium def() then returns the page - how to change that?

Tags: python, django, selenium, django-forms, django-views

For practice, I have written bot using Selenium for Instagram to do some stuff automatically and now for more practice, I would like to create a simple web page with which my bot can be controlled(like start/stop and some options)

I have written basic code in Django, it works but ... Generally when `def runInstabot(request)` starts it waits until Selenium functions(`bot.login() and bot.search()`) finish and then it returns the page. How to make that it will return the page and at the same time Selenium functions will work or even better first it will return the page and then selenium script starts?

i.e. to be more precise:
I would like to input some data(for now log in and password but later few more) then it will render for next page and at the same time/or next `bot.login() and bot.search()` starts

```
views.py:
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from bott.forms import LoginInstagramForm
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from instagram.bot import Instagram
bot = Instagram()

class InstabotView(FormView):
    template_name = 'instabot.html'
    form_class = LoginInstagramForm
    success_url = '/runinstabot/'

    def form_valid(self,form):
        form.clean_instagram()
        return super().form_valid(form)

def runInstabot(request):
    print('Welcome here')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        runInstabot.login = request.POST.get('login')
        runInstabot.password = request.POST.get('password') 
        form = LoginInstagramForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            bot.login(runInstabot.login, runInstabot.password)
            bot.search()
            return render(request, 'youbot.html')
    else:
        form = LoginInstagramForm()
```

---

```
forms.py
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class LoginInstagramForm(forms.Form):
    login = forms.CharField(label='login')
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```

---

```
urls.py
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from .views import home_page, main_page
from instagram.views import InstabotView, runInstabot

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', home_page, name='home'),
    url(r'^main/', main_page, name='main'),
    url(r'^instabot/', InstabotView.as_view(), name='instabot'),
    url(r'^runinstabot/', runInstabot, name='runinstabot'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

---

```
template:
<form action="/runinstabot/" method="post" name='btn'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.login }}
    {{ form.password }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Instagram has an API, you should use that rather than trying to power the frontend with selenium.

Comment: yes I know but I prefer to use Selenium because I would like to use it in future and probably I will have same problem